# I am trying to rename factors in R using dplyr, but i get: Error: unexpected '=' in "cbc$Gender <- recode_factor(cbc$Gender, c(0,1) ="

Tags: r, dplyr

```
cbc$Gender <- recode_factor(cbc$Gender, c(0,1) = c("Female", "Male"))
cbc$Florence <- recode_factor(cbc$Florence, c(0,1) = c("No", "Yes"))
```

Comment: Do you have `Male`, `Female` or you have `1` and `0` s??

Comment: You should look into `fct_recode`, `recode` and `recode_factor`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't work with multiple elements on the `lhs` of `=`.  Use

```
recode_factor(cbc$Gender,  `0`= "Female", `1` = "Male")
[1] Female Male   Female
Levels: Female Male
```

Or use a splicing method with named vector

```
 recode_factor(cbc$Gender, !!! setNames(c("Female", "Male"), c(0, 1)))
[1] Female Male   Female
Levels: Female Male
```

Similarly, the same options can be used in another column

---

But, this doesn't even require any `recode` as the `0`, `1` can be converted to indexes (`R` indexing starts from 1)

```
c("Female", "Male")[1 + cbc$Gender]
[1] "Female" "Male"   "Female"
```

Or may use the `base R` `factor` with `levels` and `labels` specified

```
factor(cbc$Gender, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("Female", "Male"))
```

#### data

```
cbc <- data.frame(Gender = c(0, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

### A tidyverse solution

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  tibble(
    gender = c(0,1,0,1,0,0,1)
  )

df %>% 
  mutate(
    gender = fct_recode(as.factor(gender), "Male" = "1","Female" = "0")
    )
```